# Azure subscriptions list returns empty result with MS Graph SDK

Tags: go, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

For some reason sdk doesn't return subscriptions although I have one.  I have added `Subscription.Read.All` permission to my app registration.

```golang
client := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(adapter)
res, err := client.Subscriptions().Get(nil)
```

I use the same code to get Organizations and it works fine. I use oauth2 token for sdk authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, these subscriptions from Graph SDK are a completely different thing. To get Azure subscriptions you must use Azure SDK.

P.S. and you can't issue oauth2 token both for graph and azure sdk